# Deleted Interactive Email Form Block but receiving error in Preview?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template, email-studio

Preview is failing to generate please select a Cloudpage & Data Extension and assign all fields... I've already deleted the interactive email form block but still getting this error? Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide me the complete error message? and More clarification on your query?

Comment: I found the issue, it was a small little block that was imbeded in the larger content block. once I deleted it, the issue was resolved. Very tricky

Comment: Ok,good to know.